# Custom Delaunay Refinement with CGAL Delaunay3D

Tags: mesh, cgal, delaunay

I want to perform a custom refinement strategy in a tetrahedral mesh.My input is a point cloud and I have tetrahedralized it using Delaunay 3D routine available in CGAL. The points have scalar values associated with it. Now I want to refine the tetrahedral mesh with this following strategy:
1. Get the maximum value among the vertices of each tetrahedra.
2. Get the value at the point that is going to be inserted (May be barycentre, weighted centroid or circumcenter).
3. If the difference is large enough add this point.

Any idea how to do this effectively? Note: I do not require 0-1 dimensional feature preservation.
I have already tried the above strategy. Let me show what I have done so far.

```cpp
// Assume T is Delaunay_3D triangulation CGAL mesh and I have an oracle f that tells me what is the value at the point that is going to be inserted if conditions are met.

    bool updated = true;
    int it = 0;
    while (updated)
    {
        updated = false;
        std::vector<std::pair<Point, unsigned> > point_to_be_inserted;

        for (auto cit = T.finite_cells_begin(); cit != T.finite_cells_end(); cit++)
        {


            Cell_handle c = cit;
            Point v =  Maximum valued vertex
           Point q = Point that is going to be inserted
            double val_at_new_pt = oracle(q, &pts, var);
            double ratio = std::abs(max_val - val_at_new_pt) / max_val;

            if (ratio > threshold) {
                point_to_be_inserted.emplace_back(std::make_pair(q, new_pt_ind));
                updated = true;
            }
        }
        if (updated)
        {
            std::cout << "Total pts inserted in it: " << it << " " << point_to_be_inserted.size() << std::endl;
            T.insert(point_to_be_inserted.begin(), point_to_be_inserted.end())
        }
}
```

The problem is it is quite slow (each time iterating through all the cells). I am not finding any effective strategy to do the refinement locally. I tried using a queue but the cell_handles are getting messed up after I perform one iteration of refinement. I cannot have a map that tells me whether the tetrahedra is refined or not because each time after insertion of new points cell_handles are getting created. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.